# Como transformar conteúdo de um arquivo em dicionario no Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Galera, eu tenho um arquivo e estou pegando o conteúdo dele e adicionando em uma variável. O conteúdo do arquivo e o valor da variável esta assim:

```
NAME=Maquina01
ID="MAQ 15478"
version=08
```

Eu gostaria de pegar esse conteúdo da variável e transformar em um dicionário no Python(3), assim:

```
{'NAME':'Maquina01','ID':'MAQ 15478', 'version': 08}
```

Alguém poderia me dizer como posso fazer?

Obrigado.

Comment: Módulo [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) é nativo do Python e sabe tratar arquivos INI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
value = """
NAME=Maquina01
ID="MAQ 15478"
version=08
"""

dict([ i.split('=') for i in value.strip().split('\n')])
{'NAME': 'Maquina01', 'version': '08', 'ID': '"MAQ 15478"'}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Se o seu arquivo for no formato INI, possuindo um cabeçalho devidamente definido:

```
[config]
NAME=Maquina01
ID="MAQ 15478"
version=08
```

Você pode utilizar o módulo nativo [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) do Python para interpretar o arquivo:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('data.ini')

print(dict(config['config']))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/GummyEachElectricity)</sup>

A saída seria:

```
{
    'name': 'Maquina01', 
    'id': '"MAQ 15478"', 
    'version': '08'
}
```

Comment: Muito bom eu ter conhecimento desse também, mas não é arquivo INI não.

Comment: @WilliamCanin e por que não é?

Comment: Pq era um arquivo de shellscript, eram variáveis. Queria pegar esse arquivo de variáveis em shellscript e passar em variáveis para Python.

Answer (score 0):

Usando Expressões regulares (import re):

```
import re
v=open("f.ini").read()

print(dict(re.findall(r'(\w+)=(.*)',v)))
```